# "CTF" file containing data-series, how can I open it?

Tags: r, excel, csv, metatrader4, .ctf

I'm using the software "soft4FX" which is a plugin for MetaTrader 4. This software essentially download forex/stocks... prices from freely available data sources (such as dukascopy).

All data is saved into a CTF file, I've did many research but didn't found anything on how to open and edit it. Please note I'm not a coder.

Here's a link to download a sample file (I know it's large but it contains last 10years of tick data).

[GBPUSD last 10 years tick data sample](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/Pr1PxrEY#link)

I would really appreaciate if someone can point me how to open this file and edit it in a simple way non requiring complicated softwares or programming skills. Thank's.

Comment: I suggest you contact the developer. It may be a proprietary format.  Or possibly you could import the data into mt4 which itself has the capability to export in an Excel readable format.

Comment: If you can change your source of trade data, then consider this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601872/convert-dukascopy-binary-data-to-text-dataframe-in-r/73607625#73607625